# displaying a nested div fails

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I have a nested div like this

```
<div>
<div id="nested">
</div>
</div>
```

Its style

```
#nested {
    border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 10px;
}
```

However when displaying on IE7, the nested 'div' is center-aligned. What new should I add in the style to overwrite the previous style ?

There is no center-aligned thing in firebug or chrome, only in IE7

My page structure looks like this

```
<html>
<body>
   <html>
      <body>
         <div id="nested">
         </div>
      </body>
   </html>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code you gave us is not enough. Try use firebug or chrome inspector to find which element making the div center

Comment: Try adding `float: left` to the nested div...

Comment: @MannSmokey there is a IE developer tool which you download from microsoft website, http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359

Comment: Try giving the parent div a class and then assigning the attribute of text-align:left; to it. Alternatively, like @neo108 said add float left attribute to #nested and attribute of overflow:hidden; to parent div to clear the float.

Comment: I updated my post to be more specific, this is my first time to see that odd page structure

Answer (score 0):

use conditionals

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/add-body-class-just-for-ie/

sample

html

```
 <!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US" class="no-js ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
```

css

```
 html.ie7 #nested {
        border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-top: 5px;
        text-align: left;
        width: 10px;
        float:left;
    }
```

Comment: that's on html.ie7 not body.ie7

Comment: I am using F12 on IE and viewmode is IE7, and I can change, test the style/attributes added but this "float:left" doesn't make any difference